# Appending UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

Alright, so I'm making a simple chatting application for the iPhone, and I've had some luck, it works well and looks *amazing* however I have a few problems, one such problem is the way I display rich text to the user..

Currently I have a ridiculous system, which works like this

{
send data/receive data -> add to variable allText (everything is in html)

load a webview(there are two available) with allText, in the background, when it's done loading, make it visible. (this is essentially double buffering for those familiar with game programming)

}

I have been informed that you can add html dynamically to a webview with JavaScript. I tried it, and failed miserably. Having never worked with javascript I have no idea how the whole system works, and my current system works well enough so that I would rather stick with it than learn a whole scripting langauage.

So my question is this. How could I write a function (in obj-c) to append an uiwebview with rich text?

I have tried several times, but I'm not sure where I put the tags, or if I even need tags. I am using js to scroll the uiwebview to the bottom of the loaded data, but that was a premade function that I had no hand in making.

```
-(void) addToWebView: (NSString *) toAdd{
NSString *java = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"javascript : %@",toAdd];
[classWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:java];
}
```

^That's what I'm thinking it should probably look like, I just don't know what to stinking use for the javascript!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void)addToWebView:(NSString *)toAdd {
    NSString *java = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.innerHTML += '%@'", toAdd];
    [classWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:java];
}
```

(Make sure `toAdd` doesn't contain any unescaped `'` character)

Comment: Serious?! Thank you!!! I thought it would be a lot more difficult!!! This will give me so much more flexibility and speed! Thank you!!!!